# Display payment method on review page

Tags: payment-methods

We want to display the selected payment method on the review page.
We want to place this in review.phtml

I tried this, but it did not work:

```
$payment = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle();
```

Does anyone know the correct code to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using one page checkout ?

Comment: Yes, we use one page checkout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's working fine (I tested it). But please try not to put in `<div class="order-review" id="checkout-review-load">` because it's overwrite dynamically. Put the code above or below this div.

Comment: I tried it, but I get an Magento report error, that is saying: The asked payment method is not available. With this line: app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Info.php(82)

Comment: What payment method are you using? Please try with some core method as Cash On Delivery or Check / Money order.

Comment: Well that is the problem, we use persistent checkout. So I can not reach that stap, the error is showing on the first step of the default Magento one page checkout.

Comment: You had to start with this. :) Then move the code in review/info.phtml because this is the content that is loaded dynamically in review.phtml and you won't have problems.

Comment: Well I placed the code also in review/info.phtml but it won't show up.
I placed the code before and after <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('items_before'); ?>.

Comment: Please show template path hints or write echo 'bla' to be sure that you edit the right file. Because it's working fine when I tested it.

Comment: Template path hints is: /app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
Tried a lot, but did not work. Strange that it works fine with you

Comment: It's very strange. Did you try to echo some static text?

Comment: No, because I did not know what I need to echo and exactly how. I placed this exact line in onepage/review/info.phtml: <p><?php $payment = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle(); ?></p>

Comment: I can't understand you. If you want to display the title you have echo it -> `<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethodInsta‌​nce()->getTitle(); ?>`. If it's not showing up please try with `<?php echo 'some'; ?>` and see if 'some' is showing. If it's not showing - the problem is in the place you are putting the code, if it's showing but payment method title not showing - the problem is from the code.

Comment: I'm glad that you finally made it. :) About payment and shipping address - `<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->format('html'); ?>` and `<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->format('html'); ?>`.

Comment: Great thanks a lot! 
How can I display also the payment description, beside the title? We use something like "You will be redirected to the payment page"

Comment: Better just to add only the text that you like to display (it's hard to accomplish it otherwise). Because there is no payment description. It's an additional template for some of the payments and the content of these templates is hidden by default and it's shown by JavaScript... But if you like you can view/check `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml` and `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Payment/Methods.php` -> `public function getPaymentMethodFormHtml`.